# Output 4 selected items for every another selected item

Tags: php, mysql, select

everyone! I need to select a correct number of specific items from mysql Database.

here is my schema - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jr7ky.jpg

Here is my query:

```
$servBasketData = mysql_query("SELECT services_basket.sbasket_id, system_countries.country_name, system_services.service_name, system_podservice.podservice_name, system_packets.packet_name, system_packets.price_common, system_packets.price_econom, system_packets.price_standart, system_packets.price_vip, packets_basket.sbasket_id
    FROM system_services INNER JOIN (system_podservice INNER JOIN (system_packets INNER JOIN (system_countries INNER JOIN (services_basket INNER JOIN packets_basket ON services_basket.sbasket_id = packets_basket.sbasket_id) ON system_countries.country_id = services_basket.country_id) ON system_packets.packet_id = packets_basket.packet_id) ON system_podservice.podservice_id = services_basket.podservice_id) ON system_services.service_id = services_basket.service_id ORDER BY services_basket.sbasket_id ASC;");

    while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($servBasketData)) {
        echo "<tr><td><center>".$result['sbasket_id']."</center></td><td><center>".$result['country_name']."</center></td><td><center>".$result['service_name']."</center></td><td><center>".$result['podservice_name']."/<center></td><td>";
                     echo "<tr><td><center>".$result['packet_name']."</center></td><td><center>".$result['price_common']."</center></td><td><center>".$result['price_econom']."</center></td><td><center>".$result['price_standart']."</center></td><td><center>".$result['price_vip']."</center></td>";


    }
```

This code returns me data like:

1 | russia | service1 | podservice1 |
packet1 | price_common_20 | price_econom_30 | price_standart_40 | price_vip_50

1 | russia | service1 | podservice1 |
packet2 | price_common_30 | price_econom_40 | price_standart_50 | price_vip_60

1 | russia | service1 | podservice1 |
packet3 | price_common_40 | price_econom_50 | price_standart_60 | price_vip_70

1 | russia | service1 | podservice1 |
packet4 | price_common_50 | price_econom_60 | price_standart_70 | price_vip_80

---

2 | ukraine | service1 | podservice1 |
packet1 | price_common_20 | price_econom_30 | price_standart_40 | price_vip_50

2 | ukraine | service1 | podservice1 |
packet2 | price_common_30 | price_econom_40 | price_standart_50 | price_vip_60

2 | ukraine | service1 | podservice1 |
packet3 | price_common_40 | price_econom_50 | price_standart_60 | price_vip_70

2 | ukraine | service1 | podservice1 |
packet4 | price_common_50 | price_econom_60 | price_standart_70 | price_vip_80

---

...

So, that is not I need to get. I need to get data like this:

1 | russia | service1 | podservice1 |

packet1 | price_common_20 | price_econom_30 | price_standart_40 | price_vip_50

packet2 | price_common_30 | price_econom_40 | price_standart_50 | price_vip_60

packet3 | price_common_40 | price_econom_50 | price_standart_60 | price_vip_70

packet4 | price_common_50 | price_econom_60 | price_standart_70 | price_vip_80

---

2 | ukraine | service1 | podservice1 |

packet1 | price_common_20 | price_econom_30 | price_standart_40 | price_vip_50

packet2 | price_common_30 | price_econom_40 | price_standart_50 | price_vip_60

packet3 | price_common_40 | price_econom_50 | price_standart_60 | price_vip_70

packet4 | price_common_50 | price_econom_60 | price_standart_70 | price_vip_80

---

So I need to remove duplicated data.
How I can do that? (Doesn't matter - by php or mysql)

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, could you provide the schema SQL ?

Comment: Hi! I provided it in the beginning of my post.

Is this link available? - http://i.stack.imgur.com/Jr7ky.jpg

Comment: That's your schema.. In order to help you with actual tested SQL we'de need to rewrite the SQL create table statements. What I meant was the actual SQL code for the schema.

Comment: Understood. I'll try to give you a code here.

Comment: btw have a look at my answer. I think you don't need to change the sql but instead modify the PHP a bit. (add an if statement) and one assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only difference between the first and second outputs, is that the 2nd does not include the `sbasket_id`, `service_name`,`podservice_name`.

Your problem could be solved using php to control what is outputed and when depending on when sbacket_id changes.

### Quick Example (Excuse Errors)

```
    $servBasketData = mysql_query("

    SELECT services_basket.sbasket_id,
           system_countries.country_name,
           system_services.service_name,
           system_podservice.podservice_name,
           system_packets.packet_name,
           system_packets.price_common,
           system_packets.price_econom,
           system_packets.price_standart,
           system_packets.price_vip,
           packets_basket.sbasket_id
    FROM system_services
    INNER JOIN (system_podservice
                INNER JOIN (system_packets
                INNER JOIN (system_countries
                INNER JOIN (services_basket
                INNER JOIN packets_basket ON 
    services_basket.sbasket_id = packets_basket.sbasket_id) ON 
    system_countries.country_id = services_basket.country_id) ON 
    system_packets.packet_id = packets_basket.packet_id) ON 


       system_podservice.podservice_id = services_basket.podservice_id) ON 
        system_services.service_id = services_basket.service_id
        ORDER BY services_basket.sbasket_id ASC;");

        $previous_sbasket_id = -1; 
        while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($servBasketData)) 
        {

    if($previous_sbasket_id != $result['sbasket_id'])
    {
//echo here the header if needed
echo "<tr><td><center>".$result['sbasket_id']."</center></td><td><center>".$result['country_name']."</center></td><td><center>".$result['service_name']."</center></td><td><center>".$result['podservice_name']."/<center></td><td>";

    }

//echo here everything else

    echo "<tr><td><center>".$result['packet_name']."</center></td><td><center>".$result['price_common']."</center></td><td><center>".$result['price_econom']."</center></td><td><center>".$result['price_standart']."</center></td><td><center>".$result['price_vip']."</center></td>";

    $previous_sbasket_id= $result['sbasket_id'];

    }
```

Comment: No problem. It would more difficult to do via sql. Btw, yo can use http://sqlformat.org/ or a plugin in notepad++ to format your sql. Enjoy.